# finding the order of an element in a group presentation

Tags: group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G$ be a group given by
$$G \ =\ \langle \ x, \  y \mid x^4 =\ y^4=1, \ yx =\ x^2\ y^2 \rangle$$
I found  $\ G/G'$ to be isomorphic to $C_4$.
What can we say about the order of $\ x$ in $G$?
The final answer is $4$.
But $\ x^4 = 1$ in $G$ means that $x^4$ belong to the normal closure of $R$ where $R$ is the relations in $G$.

I can't see the connection. Can any one help?

Comment: I'm just curious: how did you find G/G' isomorphic to C4?

Comment: @YipJungHon: If $G$ is presented by $\langle X\;|\;R\rangle$, then $G/G'$ can be presented by $\langle X\;|\;R\cup C\rangle$, where $C = \{[x_i,x_j]\;|\;x_i, x_j\in X\}$. From this it is not hard to see that, for the group $G$ of this problem, $G/G'$ contains only the elements $G', xG', (xG')^2, (xG')^3=yG'$. To see that these four elements must be distinct in the presented group, it suffices to observe that there exists a group, namely $C_4=\{1,g,g^2,g^3\}$, which has an element $x:=g$ of order $4$ and another element $y:=g^{-1}$ which satisfies all relations in the presentation.

Comment: Just curious, if I define the group slightly differently, with it being: $G=<x,y |  x^4=y^4=5>,$ it will still be $\cong$ to  $C_4$ right?

Comment: @Yip Jung Hon by adding the relation xy=yx the group become abelian and hence from the last relation you have x=y and simply remove the generator y you left with x^4=1

Comment: In G/G' you only make the generators abelian

Comment: But then G/G' must be abelian even if I remove the condition y=x, so that condition doesn't really change anything?

Comment: @YipJungHon The symbol "$5$" is meaningless in this context, while the symbol "$1$" denotes the empty word (the identity in the ambient free group). So your question doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can we say about the order of $x$ in $G$?

If $x^n$ is a relator of $G$ then the only think you can say for certain is that $x$ has order *dividing* $n$.

For example, consider the following two presentations:
$$
\langle a, b, c\mid a^3, b^4, c^{6}, a=b, b^2=c^2\rangle
$$
and
$$
\langle x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4\mid x_ix_{i+1}=x_{i+2}\rangle
$$
(where subscripts are computed modulo $5$).

In the first group, we see that the elements $a$ and $b$ are the same and so must have order diving both $3$ and $4$. Hence, they have order $1$ and are trivial: $a=b=1$. Then $c^6=1$ and $c^2=b^2=1$ so $c^2=1$. It turns out that $c$ actually has order $2$.

For the second group, it was a famous "fun" problem of John Conway to work out what this group is. It "clearly" does not have any elements of finite order. However, it is actually cyclic of order $11$...

Group presentations can be tricky beasts :-)

Answer (score 2):

The relation $x^4=1$ guarantees that the order of $x$ in $G$ is at most $4$. The fact that $xG'$ generates $G/G'\cong C_4$ guarantees that the order of $x$ in $G$ is at least $4$.

Comment: Thank you . @Keith Kearnes The relation you mentioned is saying that $\ x^4 $ belong to the normal closer of R so $\ x^4R = \ R$ Where can we say that the order must be at least 4

Comment: The answer explains exactly why the order is at least $4$.

Comment: @Derek Holt but he talked about the order of x in G/G'. How this is connected to the order of x in G

Comment: The order of $xG'$ in $G/G'$ is $4$, so the order of $x$ in $G$ is at least $4$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the normal closure is even bigger than the subgroup generated by the relation. The only thing that has to be shown is that the order is, in fact, 4 and not less. Since the order divides 4, this boils down to showing that $x^2$ is not in the normal closure. Let $N$ be this normal closure, and let $R \le N$ be the subgroup generated by the relations. By considering the powers of $x$ and $y$ occuring in any element of $R$, we find that $x^2 \notin R$. But the normal closure is precisely the union of $fRf^{-1}$ ($f \in F\langle x, y \rangle$, the free group over $x$ and $y$), and we see that $x^2$ is not in any of these sets. Thus, $x^2$ is nonzero in your group $G$.

Comment: Thank you . But why you are saying that $\ x^2$ is not in R can you clarify

Comment: can you clarify